# CommandLink within PrimeFaces Mobile DataList is not referencing the correct element after being filtered

Tags: primefaces

I'm working on a PrimFaces mobile employee directory app and have hit a road block.  Its a simple app which consists of two screens (employee filter/list + employee detail).

I was able to load a datalist without issues.  Clicking on the commandlink properly loads the employee detail.  I then was able to implement a custom employee filter which was somewhat painful, but I got that working.  The filter works by repopulating the employee datalist's model with the filtered results.

The issue is, after I use the filter to repopulate/filter the datalist, clicking on an employee (commandlink) does not pass the correct employee ID back to the model.  Instead, the employee ID that was there before the filter was performed is passed.  It's like the JSF model is not matching the DOM.

I'm using:

- TomEE (MyFaces 2.1.7)
- PrimeFaces Mobile 0.9.3
- PrimeFaces 3.3

Both of my backing models are @ViewScoped

```
<pm:view id="peopleDirView" onload="">
        <pm:header title="People Directory" fixed="true">
        </pm:header>

        <pm:content>
            <h:form id="form">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <p:inputText id="searchCriteria" value="#{peopleDirectoryBean.criteria}" type="search"
                            onkeyup="delay(function() {filterResults();}, 500);" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <p:dataList id="peopleDataList" value="#{peopleDirectoryBean.people}" var="person" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandLink action="#{peopleDirectoryDetailBean.loadPersonDetail(person.employeeId)}" update=":personDetailView">
                            <img src="/phonedir/people/image/#{person.employeeId}?width=75&amp;height=100" width="90" height="100"
                                onerror="missingImage(this);" id="per-search-picture" />
                            <h1>#{person.nameLast}, #{person.nameFirst}</h1>
                            <p>#{person.deptName}</p>
                            <p>#{person.jobTitle}</p>
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataList>
                <p:remoteCommand name="filterResults" update="peopleDataList" action="#{peopleDirectoryBean.peopleSearch}" />
            </h:form>
        </pm:content>

        <pm:footer fixed="true">
            <pm:navBar>
                <p:button value="People" icon="home" href="#peopleDirView?reverse=true" styleClass="ui-btn-active" />
                <p:button value="Locations" icon="info" href="#locationsView?reverse=true" />
                <p:button value="Conference" icon="search" href="#conferenceRoomsView?reverse=true" />
            </pm:navBar>
        </pm:footer>

        <script>
            var delay = (function() {
                var timer = 0;
                return function(callback, ms) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
                };
            })();

            function missingImage(image) {
                image.onerror = "";
                image.src = "missing-person.jpg";
                return true;
            }
        </script>

</pm:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like the mistake was on my part.

In my backing bean, I was using javax.inject.Named (@Named) because I was trying to make use of my container's ability to do CDI.  Once I changed it to javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean (@ManagedBean ) the problem went away.  The TomEE docs state that it supports @Named so I'm not sure what the deal is.